# do you call them functions, procedures or methods?

Tags: oop, theory

consider a standard c# 'function'

public void foo()
{
//some code
}

In c or c++ this is called a 'function' - even if taking no parameters and returning no value. In another language maybe it would be a 'procedure'.
In object orientation speak it would be called a 'method' if a class member.
What would be the correct term to use in c#?

Answer (score 4):

- Method : function of a class.
- Function : function out of a class, possible only in full-object languages (like C++, C, etc.)
- Procedure : function that return nothing/void. I personnaly don't like this word, I'd rather use 'function'

Make your choice =)

*Edit* : Just to be more precise, Method, function and procedure are OOP words to describe a subroutine. Some languages have their own vocabulary such as "predicate" in Prolog, or "constructor" in C++/C#/Java, or even "property" in C#.

Comment: A Prolog predicate is far from a subroutine.  Languages with subroutines, Algol derivatives, consist of imperative statements plus expressions.  I would opine that a language without statements cannot have subroutines, even though it can have functions.   Is "y = 2 *x + b" a subroutine?  A function?  ;)

Comment: @Heath you're right, especially for the Prolog. I guess subroutine isn't appropriated. I might edit to deleted it..

Answer (score 2):

Just to confuse the issue futher: (from C# Language Specification)

> [7.4 Function members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691334.aspx)
>   Function members are members that contain executable statements. Function members are always members of types and cannot be members of namespaces. C# defines the following categories of function members:
>       * Methods
>       * Properties
>       * Events
>       * Indexers
>       * User-defined operators
>       * Instance constructors
>       * Static constructors
>       * Destructors

And

> [10. Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645599.aspx)
>   A class is a data structure that may contain data members (constants and fields), **function members** (methods, properties, events, indexers, operators, instance constructors, destructors and static constructors), and nested types. Class types support inheritance, a mechanism whereby a derived class can extend and specialize a base class.

So "function member" or "method" would be correct for C#.

Answer (score 2):

Method is OOP **abstraction** term. They describe behaviour(a verb) of an object.
They are equivalent to some of the procedural programming's functions and procedures.
(the properties etc are also function and procedures).

So, function is a program within program that returns some values.
Procedure is a program within program that does something.
Methods, Properties etc, etc are a next level of abstraction(used in OOP). They are wrapped around functions and procedures.

Answer (score 1):

I think in C# call it a method because C# is object oriented language.

Comment: What about a JavaScript function? Should we call it a method too?

Answer (score 1):

If a "Function" is part of a class I call it a method.

If I was coding in C (i.e. in proceedural or non OO idiom) I call it a function.

I personally don't use the word proceedure to refer to a "Function"

Answer (score 1):

I thought (in Ada) that a 'procedure' is the correct term generally, and a 'function' is a procedure which is guaranteed to be side-effect free, that is, it only reads from and does manipulation on data, and returns it, but does not write anything or have any 'side-effects'.

I'm a Java guy anyway, I call everything a function even though it should be called a method.

Answer (score 0):

I think method is the correct term, but I doubt you'll get any funny glares for using any of the other suggested names.

Answer (score 0):

Since I spent a lot of time with ADA I would call that a "procedure" since it has no return value. If it had a return value, I would have called it a "function".

I've never seen the point of saying "Method", though that is most likely the correct term to use when talking about functions/procedures that are members of a class. Never really saw the use of yet another term for the same thing.